# Writing PDF Output with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pdf

I am trying to port some code from an older version of QGIS. I have managed to get the map setup fairly to my liking, and can export some content via a command like

```
iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("example.png")
```

However, I want to export to PDF, and also add a legend for my graduated color scale.  I've been rummaging around the documentation online for some time but I can't figure out how these new classes work together.

@JoshC helped me to understand that I need to use the QgsLayout and QgsLayoutExporter classes, not mapCanvas, however I'm not clear on how to use those classes to get out a PDF with a legend.

Comment: There's nothing for PDFs that references `mapCanvas`, but if you use the `QgsLayout` and `QgsLayoutExporter` classes, you should be able to add the legend and call [exportToPdf](http://python.qgis.org/api/core/Layout/QgsLayoutExporter.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutExporter.exportToPdf).

Comment: Thanks. I guess my next question then is how to use the QgsLayout class. In particular, how do I transform what's on the mapCanvas into the layout that I can export?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a small example of how you could use it:

```
projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
layoutmanager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
layout_item = layoutmanager.layoutByName("test")  # test is the layout name
export = QgsLayoutExporter(layout_item)
export.exportToImage(filename, QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
```

layout_item is the reference to your QgsLayout.  Hope it helps

Comment: I've tried using this to export a map layout, but it does not work for me.  My "filename" is a path to my desktop. I'm saving it as a .jpg file.  Is this exactly the code you use to export a Print Layout?

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work for me"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I restarted QGIS and now the script works.  I think that happens from time to time.