# Printing QGIS-3 saved layout to image using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, layout-manager

I know that one can create a layout and set the various elements there in programmatically using pyqgis (See e.g. [Print Layout Items. setExtent() and attemptResize()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309219)).

But in my application, I have a saved complex layout with multiple sub-figures/maps, which was created manually with QGIS 3 (as of 3.22). I can access it from the menus at `Project -> Layout Manager` and then `show`. And I can then print it. I tried but didn't find good examples of how to do such complex layouts in Python (and I didn't want to repeat the labor either).

How can one using PyQGIS to print map using a saved layout to an image file (.png)?